# How to select the higher count element in powershell using groupby?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a list in powershell which contain the elements 1,2,2,2

On using the command

```
$list_of_instance| Group-Object -NoElement
```

I get the following output:

```
Count Name
----- ----
  1     1
  3     2
```

Now because the elements 2 have a count of 3, I want to select this elements from the list and store the element 2 in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `Sort-Object` to sort on property Count, next append `Select-Object` to select the last one in the sorted list and put the `Name` property in a variable

```
$list_of_instance = 1,2,2,2
$var = ($list_of_instance| Group-Object -NoElement | Sort-Object Count | Select-Object -Last 1).Name
```

`$var` will now have a **string** value of "2"

If you want the $var to have the same type as the original, remove the `-NoElement` switch and go for the first item in the group:

```
$list_of_instance = 1,2,2,2
$var = ($list_of_instance| Group-Object | Sort-Object Count | Select-Object -Last 1).Group[0] 
$var
```